# The function setState is not defined

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, barcode-scanner

I am trying to make a barcode scanner inside my mobile app. I made a file that's called barcode_scanner.dart and one called barcode_scanner_bloc.dart. I am trying to write scan() method inside the barcode_scanner_bloc.dart and call it from barcode_scanner.dart.
For that I did this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'barcode_scanner_bloc.dart';

class ScanBarcode extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScanBarcodeState createState() => _ScanBarcodeState();

  static scan() {}
}

class _ScanBarcodeState extends State<ScanBarcode> {
  String barcode = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('Code Scanner'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.purple,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                onPressed: scan,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.scanner, size: 40),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Camera Scan'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 2,
                        ),
                        Text('Click here')
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
              child: Text(
                barcode,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
            
          ],
          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And now I am trying to add the scan() method, but when I try to do that in another file, it gives the error. Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'barcode_scanner.dart';




Future scan() async {
  try {
    String barcode = await ScanBarcode.scan();
    setState(() {
      this.barcode = barcode;
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == ScanBarcode.CameraAccessDenied) {
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = 'camera permission not granted';
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e';
      });
    }
  } on FormatException {
    setState(() {
      this.barcode = 'null (user returned using the back button)';
    });
  } catch (e) {
    setState(() {
      this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e';
    });
  }
}
```

If someone could help me I would be really happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't access  `setState` from outside the `StatefulWidget`

try making your `scan()` function with in the `StatefulWidget` class

or try to make the `scan()` function return the value of `barcode` then call `setState`

so it would be like

```
Future<String> scan() async {
  try {
    String barcode = await ScanBarcode.scan();
    return barcode;
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == ScanBarcode.CameraAccessDenied) {
        return 'camera permission not granted';
    } else {
       return 'Unknown error: $e';
    }
  } on FormatException {
    return  'null (user returned using the back button)';
  } catch (e) {
     return  'Unknown error: $e';
  }
}
```

and in your `ScanBarcode` class

```
onPressed: () async {
setState(() {
        this.barcode = await scan();
      });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you either need to set up a notification and listener pattern or streams with stream controllers. I personally use flutter_bloc package to do this (there are full flutter tutorials available for each of these on youtube). with flutter_bloc you would call scan() from your widget like this:

```
bloc.add(ScanEventStart());
```

Basically you send the BLoC an event and it returns state to your widget's BlocBuilder widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both! I have one more question if you can answer, in this **if (e.code == ScanBarcode.CameraAccessDenied)** part it gives the error of 'The getter CameraAccessDenied isn't defined for the type ScanBarcode' how should I integrate it? I am new to coding and flutter, so I don't know these type of things.